# OpenGL 3.3 won't draw my triangle

Tags: c, opengl

I'm following these tutorials using C instead of C++:
[Tutorial 2](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial02/tutorial02.html), [short extension to tutorial 2](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial03/tutorial03.html).

The only change I made to port it was changing `Vector3f[3]` into `GLfloat[9]`. The version with `GLfloat[1]` instead of `Vector3f[1]` works correctly. I think this change might be the reason of `glDrawArrays` not working but I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

GLuint VBO_id;

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_id);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
    GLfloat Vertices[9] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                            1.0f, 0.0f };

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, 
                 GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 03");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);

    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
        return 1;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    CreateVertexBuffer();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline).

> OpenGL 3.0 was the last revision of the specification which fully supported both fixed and programmable functionality. Even so, most hardware since the OpenGL 2.0 generation lacked the actual fixed-function hardware. Instead, fixed-function processes are emulated with shaders built by the system.
>
> In OpenGL 3.2, the Core Profile lacks these fixed-function concepts. The compatibility profile keeps them around. However, most newer features of OpenGL cannot work with fixed function, even when it might seem theoretically possible for them to interact.

Sounds like your version of OpenGL doesn't support the fixed function pipeline. Either use an older version of OpenGL that does or write and load a shader as shown in [Tutorial 4](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial04/tutorial04.html).

Comment: I've did fixed function pipeline and everything was alright. I also did load shaders in my last question but my triangle still isn't drawn. I also started using VAO in addition to VBO. Still no change. I don't know what to do. I will improve my last question and put a bounty on it...

Comment: It turns out I created a function to initialize VAO and VBO... but forgot to call it. I'm sorry I've wasted your time.

Comment: Not a waste of time -- you got to a solution, whether it was this answer that helped you or not! Glad you figured it out. ;-)

Comment: @Xis88 Maybe you should post your answer too.